# How to get the Font Name from the Font file?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have downloaded a Font file from the internet and the name of the font file is nuku1.ttf.
I have to use that in my application so I activated that by using this.     `CTFontManagerSetAutoActivationSetting(FontPath,2);`. After activating this font file how can get the font name for that file Programmatically? In other words where the AutoActivated Fonts are stored in mac?

Comment: Be more patient. It'd only been an hour. People don't just sit on Stack Overflow all day waiting for something to answer; we all check our feed(s) in our own time. Plus, many of us live in different time zones, so the person with your answer may be asleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CTFontManagerSetAutoActivationSetting(FontPath,2);
> ```

[The `CTFontManagerSetAutoActivationSetting` function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_FontManager_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFontManagerSetAutoActivationSetting) takes a bundle identifier, not the path to a font. (Also, you should use [the value names](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_FontManager_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CTFontManagerAutoActivationSetting), not hard-coded numeric literals.)

To examine a font file, use [the `CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorsFromURL` function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_FontManager_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorsFromURL) to create an array of [CTFontDescriptor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFontDescriptorRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005107) objects, one for each of the fonts in the file. Each descriptor will tell you the font's PostScript name, family name, and display name, among other attributes.